# Is it possible to call SubtleCrypto methods from a worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, interface, webcrypto-api

I would like to call methods of [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) from a worker.
Usually, it is possible via the Crypto.subtle properties available in a window context :

Eg: `window.crypto.subtle.encrypt()`

In a worker, window is not available, but crypto can still be accessed this way :

```
self.crypto
```

However `self.crypto.subtle` always return undefined.
Is this normal behaviour (eg: disabled for security purposes) or is there a possibility to call SubtleCrypto methods from worker ?

I have created a JSFiddle that reproduce behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/746mjgty/).
I use Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Deprecations and Removals in Chrome 60](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations):

> **crypto.subtle now requires a secure origin**
>
> The [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) which has been supported since Chrome 37 has always worked on non-secure origins. Because of Chrome's long-standing policy of [preferring secure origins for powerful features](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features?pli=1), `crypto.subtle` is now only visible on secure origins.
>
> [Intent to Remove](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/blink-dev/ZD3NWqkk-bo/discussion) | [Chromium Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=641526)

The following code, when placed on HTTPS server, has `crypto.subtle` and works just fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="start" type="button" value="Start">

    <script>
      function getWorkerJS() {
        var js = `
            onmessage = function(e) {
                var jwkKey = {
                    kty: "oct",
                    k: "lckjnFLIEas7yf65ca6saksjhcajs554s5cajshgGGG"
                };
                crypto.subtle.importKey(
                    "jwk", jwkKey, {name: "AES-CBC"}, true,
                    ['encrypt', 'decrypt', 'wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']
                )
                .then(
                    function (result) {
                        postMessage({ success: true});
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        postMessage({ message: error.message });
                    }
                );
            };
        `;
        var blob = new Blob([js], {"type": "text/plain"});
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      }

      var ww = new Worker(getWorkerJS());

      ww.onmessage = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.data);
      };

      document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start, false);

      function start() {
        ww.postMessage('start');
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I try to run any method on SubtleCrypto.prototype I got the following message: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'digest' on 'SubtleCrypto': Illegal invocation` while it works with `window.crypto.subtle`

Comment: @tigrou, sorry, my bad. Updated.